# ASP.NET Validation of Viewstate MAC failed on Button Press

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, machinekey

When I try and click on a button in my asp.net web form I am thrown an error that states:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that  configuration specifies the same validationKey and validation algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster.
>
> See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=314055 for more information.

The html code is as follows:

```
<asp:Button Text="Create New NetEvent" runat="server" ID="testBtn" OnClick="testBtn_Click"/>
```

My CodeBehind file is never reached as the error is thrown before the new page loads. I am able to open the page I am trying to navigate to separately and it works I am just not able to make a Server.Transfer call in C# to get to it. My c# code is as follows:

```
protected void testBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Server.Transfer("~/NetEvent/NetEvent/Default.aspx");
    }
```

Comment: Use a different PostBack URL instead of a server transfer to handle the form post.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this a little?

Comment: Are you just trying to redirect to a different page when you click the button? Seems like a job for a good old fashioned anchor tag to me. Or use an `<asp:LinkButton />` with a `href` property.

Comment: Use it like this: `<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" PostBackUrl="~/Page2.aspx" />`

Comment: That worked thanks!